# SiriKit: Cannot reply to a message

Tags: ios, siri, sirikit

I just added the `Intents Extension` to my Project, and decided to try it out using the example code that is added by default.

I select the Siri target, run on the device, Siri pops up and I start with: "Search messages in [MyApp]".
Method `handleSearchForMessages` is executed in `IntentHandler.m` and Siri responds *You have a message from Sarah*.

After reading the message, Siri asks *Would you like to reply?*
But when I answer *Yes*, I get:

`I don't see an app for that. You'll need to download one.`

The weird thing is that when I try the same on a brand new Project, it works, even without enabling the capabilities.

I really don't know why in my project works the part of searching messages, but not the part of replying.

Of course in the `Info.plist` I have the 3 default Intents for messaging.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please show ur IntentHandler code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I kinda solved the issue or at least found a workaround:

I have 2 targets, one for PROD and other for Staging environment.
The display name of the app in both targets are same, but matches only the name of the target for PROD.

The Intents Extension was embed in the Staging Target, where I was getting the error mentioned above.

However, I tried exactly the same directly on the PROD target and it worked.

Provisioning profile and capabilities are same for both targets, so I assume is related to the mismatch between the name of the app and the name of the target built